# Android - OnTouch Do Work

Tags: android, touch, action

I have some code that has got me very close to what Im trying to achieve.  But there are a few issues.  What I want to do is, when a Button is pressed and held, it will continuously call a method AdvanceLog().  The problem is, the ACTION_DOWN motion event does not continue to get called.  What happens is, when you press and hold, the first motion is ACTION_DOWN and every motion thereafter while still holding down is ACTION_MOVE.
This is causing some issues, as I am not REALLY looking for the move action, more so just the repetetive down action.  Any suggestions?

```
advanceButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                int counter=0;
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    fwdTouchCounter++;
                    AdvanceLog(true, true);
                    try 
                    {
                        if(fwdTouchCounter>5)                           
                            Thread.sleep(30);
                        else
                            Thread.sleep(800);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    fwdTouchCounter=0;

                return false;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `ACTION_DOWN` touch event, fire off a thread that calls a local method. Inside this method constantly read a class variable (`boolean` is easiest) and if that variable, let's call it `m_advanceLog` is true, continue to process (advancing your log I'm guessing). In your `ACTION_UP` touch event, set `m_advanceLog` to false which should stop your loop and allow the thread to exit.

Keep in mind that this is only a good idea if there aren't user interface changes, othwerwise some additional work is needed due to the thread interaction.

Comment: @MattBishop  hi, I am having a problem quite similar to the above mentioned. Instead of detecting my finger that is touching the screen and stationary, it is constantly firing Action_Move! Please take a look at my code and I'd appreciate your input. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074817/surfaceview-multi-touch-motionevent-action-move-gets-executed-wrongly-and-conti