# Android Multitouch

Tags: android, button, textview, multi-touch

I am developing an application in which I have 4 Buttons that, when pressed, valorize 4 different text boxes showing which one is pressed and which is not.
All inputs are given at the same time, hence I need to use multitouch.

I could not find any good example.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: And where is your code? Do you want to keep it super-secret?

Comment: I am still figuring out a way to do it. Donot know where to start from

Comment: Here is a great [starting point](https://www.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

"You can do it easily by running few threads that will listen to TouchEvent and update the UI with an handler"

Basically you will do a thread for each button...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15063889/3180983

I don't get why you got -4 vote... Except that this is a duped question...