# SurfaceView Multi-Touch MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE gets executed, wrongly and continously?

Tags: android

I have a SurfaceView on which I am trying to detect MultiTouch and am debugging it by using Log.e.

MY PROBLEM: when I test my app on the phone all the Motion events are correctly detected, but for some reason if my finger is just at a stationary point on the screen not moving, the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE keeps getting fired!!

So basically both, finger Up & Down work fine, but while the finger is down (and not moving), still for some reason the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE keeps getting called until the finger is lifted up?!

here is the code of my Touch Event

```
   @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

// get pointer index from the event object
int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

// get pointer ID
int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

// get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
int maskedAction = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) ;

CharSequence s;

switch (maskedAction) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    Log.e("XXXX", "DOWN");
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
  Log.e("XXXX", "Pointer DOWN");
  break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { // a pointer was moved
  Log.e("XXXX", "MOVE");
  break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    Log.e("XXXX", "UP");

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
    Log.e("XXXX", "Pointer UP");

case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
  Log.e("XXXX", "CANCEL");
break;
}
}
invalidate();
return true;
}
```

In my Log.e out put i get this sort of a result even if my finger is still and not moving.

```
DOWN
Pointer DOWN
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
MOVE
Pointer UP
UP
CANCEL
```

My finger never moves its stationary, i have double checked it by logging the X & y co ordinate values too.
Can someone explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure its really stationary?  A pixel is really small, its next to impossible to not move it even 1 of them for an extended period.  And if it really is stable, did you check the historicalX and Y values to see if it possibly moved and came back?  Historical values are additional move events that got bundled into 1 call.    In addition, are you sure none of the other parameters of the touch changed, such as size or pressure?  If so you'd also receive a move event to be informed of that.

Comment: 1000% stationary.i never used Historical X & Y, but i did display X & Y cordinates every time it kept entering into the  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE part of my touch event, and they were identical to the 4th decimal place.
No all other parameters are same.
very weird, this doesnt happen on my GenyMotion Emulator, but i tested it on 2 mobiles, One+ 1, and my LG optimus2x. Both, the Action move keeps firing.

Comment: A single MOVE event can actually be a dozen, or a hundred moves batched into 1 (although a dozen is as bad as I've ever seen it).  The X and Y are only the final values.  Each of the values in getHistoricalX and getHistoricalY are also moves that you didn't see until this moment.